# Type ranges in type member refinement

Tags: scala, types

```
class Animal
class Cat extends Animal

trait ZPar {
  type K
  def get(i: K)
}

def zz(t:ZPar{ type K >: Animal } ) = {
   t.get(new Cat) //compiled! why?
}
```

This code compiles without errors, but I assumed that there must be an issue because `K >: Animal` and I'm passing `Cat` which is definitely not super type of `Animal`.

Is it something wrong with compiler or I just misunderstood the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argument of `t.get` must have type `t.K`. The compiler doesn't know exactly what type that is, but it does know it's a supertype of `Animal` and therefore of `Cat`. So any value of type `Cat` has type `t.K` as well.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It's not necessary that `new Cat` is of type Cat.</strike> `new Cat` can be not only of type `Cat`. It can be of types `Cat`, `Animal`, `AnyRef` or `Any`.

<strike>So here `K` is inferred to be minimal possible type, i.e. `Animal`.</strike>

Comment: One minor disagreement: it _is_ necessary, it's just not the only type of `new Cat`. One less minor: `K` isn't inferred to be anything.